# AWS/Android Unable to calculate md5 hash

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, md5

I'm customising Amazon's S3 Uploader sample program to suit my needs. After a bucket is created, I upload a video to it.

```
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(buckets.get(0).getName(), Constants.VIDEO_NAME, new java.io.File(filePath));
```

When I run the line above I get back the exception below:

```
Unable to calculate MD5 has: /storage/....../bla.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission Denied)
```

Stack Trace:

```
12-04 14:39:21.981  29372-29441/com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader E/ERR﹕ com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20131203_180120.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1139)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:160)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:120)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20131203_180120.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1135)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:160)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:120)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1135)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:160)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:120)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

OS = 4.4/KitKat, Device = Nexus 4

What's going on?

Comment: full stack trace, device version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From KitKat, you can't read external storage without the permission.

See

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Behaviors

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: AND may have to call ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)

Answer (score 4):

Don't be like me.  Check that the file exists before attempting to upload to S3.